# Convergent series and comparison test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that the series converges, but not absolutely: $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\Bigg(\exp\Bigg(\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\Bigg)-1\Bigg)$.

This is what I did so far:

$\exp\Bigg(\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}\Bigg)-1=\exp(\frac{1}{n})-1>0$ when $n$ is even

$\exp\Bigg(\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}\Bigg)-1=\exp(\frac{-1}{n})-1<0$ when $n$ is odd

So, $\Bigg|\exp\Bigg(\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}\Bigg)-1\Bigg|\leq\exp(\frac{1}{n})$. I was going to use comparison test but now stuck. Any hints?

Comment: $\exp(\frac1n)\to1$ when $n\to\infty$ and it is bad, so you need more thin estimate. Then you may use Leibniz's test http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test.

Comment: Ya I know it is bad, that's why I was stuck. But here I cannot use Leibniz's test directly because I have an exp part.

Comment: Out of 14 questions asked, you've never accepted an answer to any of them. If people take the time to answer your questions, the least you can do is accept it when it's good. Here you've got two suitable answers and you did not even vote up, we're not at your disposal..

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $\exp(x) = 1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3!+ \cdots$ for any $x$, so
$$
\exp(\frac{(-1)^n}{n}) = 1 + \frac{(-1)^n}{n} + \frac{1}{2!}\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)^2 + \dots.
$$
Then 
$$
\Bigg|\exp\Bigg(\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}\Bigg)-1\Bigg|\leq\frac{2}{n} \to 0.
$$
Indeed
$$
\Bigg|\exp\Bigg(\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}\Bigg)-1\Bigg|\leq\frac{1}{n} + \Bigg|\frac{1}{2!}\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{3!}\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)^3 + \dots\Bigg| 
\leq \frac{1}{n} + \Bigg|\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^3 + \dots\Bigg| \leq \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\frac{n}{n-1} \leq \frac{2}{n}.
$$
Let's prove monotony. I'm going to show that $|a_{2n+1}|<|a_{2n}|<|a_{2n-1}|$.
For $2n$ we have
$$
|a_{2n}| = \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2!}\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2 +  \frac{1}{3!}\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^3 + \dots
$$
Then
$$
|a_{2n+1}| \leq\frac{1}{2n+1} + \frac{1}{2!}\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)^2 +\dots < \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2!}\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2 +\dots < \frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} \leq |a_{2n-1}|.
$$
Now by Leibniz's test the series converges.

As mvggz noted the series doesn't converge absolutely because $|a_n|\sim \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Can you please explain how did you use Leibniz's test here?

Comment: As you wrote down the series is alternating ($a_n>0$ for even $n$ and $a_n<0$ for odd $n$) and as I shown $|a_n|\to0$ monotonically. This is Leibniz's test.

Comment: Oh, got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an expansion of your general term, that I'll note $U_n$ :

$$ U_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n} + O(\frac{1}{n^2}) $$

You can then apply the alternate series test to $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ and prove that $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges. This proves that $U_n$ does as well.

As for the absolute convergence, suppose your series does: Then you can write $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ as the sum of two general terms of absolutely converging series.

$\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ = $U_n + O(\frac{1}{n^2}) $

This implies that $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges absolutely (triangular inequality), which is false. Hence your series doesn't converge absolutely.

Comment: I included you remarks.

Comment: Well then I'll upvote, it's neat :)